# How do we calculate the amount by which a majority increases the probability of being right?

Tags: probability

My question was inspired by this passage:

> As an adaptive learner, what do you do when
> any observable differences in skill, success, and
> prestige among individuals do not covary with
> the observable differences in behaviour, beliefs,
> practices. or values? For example, suppose every­
> one in your village uses blowguns for hunting,
> except one regular guy who uses a bow and
> arrow, and obtains fairly average hunting returns.
> Do you adopt the bow or the blowgun? One
> solution for dealing with such information­
> poor dilemmas is to copy the behaviours.
> beliefs and strategies of the majority (Boyd and
> Richerson, 1985; Henrich and Boyd, 1998).
> Termed conformist transmission, this mechanism allows individuals to aggregate information over the behaviour of many individuals. Because these
> behaviours implicitly contain the effects of each
> individual's own experience and learning efforts,
> conformist transmission can be the best route to
> adaptation in information-poor environments.
> To see this, suppose every individual is given
> a noisy signal (a piece of information) from the
> environment about what the best practice is
> in the current circumstances. This information,
> for anyone individual, might give them a 60%
> chance of noticing that blowguns bring back
> slightly larger returns than bows. Thus, using
> individual learning alone, learners will adopt
> the more efficient hunting practice with proba­
> bility 0.60. But, if an individual samples the
> behaviour of 10 other individuals, and simply
> adopts the majority behaviour, his chances of
> adopting the superior blowgun technology
> increase to 75%.

Source: https://henrich.fas.harvard.edu/files/henrich/files/henrich_mcelreath_2007.pdf

I was wondering how they calculated this.

To formulate my question precisely, suppose you have a group of 10 people considering a question with two possible answers and each has a 60% chance of getting the right answer. What's the chance that a majority (at least 6 people) get the right answer?

Here's how I attempted to go about this. Let's start by looking at the odds of one particular situation coming about. Take a scenario where 3 people get it right and 7 people get it wrong. What are the odds of this?

Well, the odds of 3 people getting it right is (.6)^3 and the odds of 7 people getting it wrong is (.4)^7. So we have (.6)^3 * (.4)^7 = 0.000353894. Now in how many ways can this happen? 10 choose 3 = 120. So 0.000353894 * 120 = 0.042467328.

Thus, it seems we have a general method here. Simply add up the probabilities for the configurations where 6-10 people get it right. I wrote some python code to do this:

```
def GroupChance(avg, number_people):
    
    majority = int(number_people/2 + 1)
    
    chance=0
    
    for i in range(majority, number_people+1):
        chance += avg**i * (1-avg)**(number_people-i) * n_choose_k(number_people, i)
    
    return chance
```

However, when I invoke it with GroupChance(.6, 10) to denote a group of 10 people with a likelihood of 60% of getting the right answer, it gives me  0.6331032576, far less than 75% and actually closer to %60. Is my method wrong or did the authors of that paper make a mistake?

Comment: There's something fishy in the argument regardless of the probabilities. When you decide to use a blowgun in a village that has one bow-and-arrow hunter, you're not measuring the observations of ten other people about which hunting method is better, you're observing the fact that ten other people *also* followed the majority. IIRC there's a phenomenon in evolutionary biology whereby a trait can become almost universal in a population despite not having any particular advantage over the alternative trait.

Comment: Yes @DavidK , good point. The argument assumes that you are the only conformist. This weakness can be invoked in explaining why one doesn't follow the majority. If you have a dissenting opinion and someone asks you why you don't go with the majority because they are statistically more likely to be right, you can respond that they are conformists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are correct, the authors have made some error. It's not clear to me where they got 75% from. The same calculation for "at least 5" gives 0.834 instead, which is also rather far from 75%.

The same calculation for the cumulative distribution function for the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) is also built into the scipy module, which may be preferable. Eg,

```
from scipy.stats import binom
z = 1 - binom.cdf(k=5, n=10, p=0.6)
print(z)
# 0.6331032576
```

Comment: My brother pointed out that it seems to matter whether the number is even or odd. If you have 9 people, it's about 73% and if you have 11, it's just about 75%. This effect seems to come from the fact that in odd cases there is no even split.

Comment: @IsaacD.Cohen That's an interesting point. Perhaps the authors meant that the individual samples 10 others in addition to themself?